# Python-How would i go about getting block of text from an html document

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

https://www.cpms.osd.mil/Content/AF%20Schedules/survey-sch/111/111R-03Apr2003.html
This is the page I am trying to parse. It's from a government site which in my experience are not known for keeping up their certificates, so you are are going to be warned about it not being safe by your browser. All I want is this part,https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lWCT.jpg.

edit: Sorry, for the lack of information. I started asking this question then I got called away at work. It's no excuse but when I came back it was time to go home so, I just kinda hit submit.

I have already tried doing it more "manually" but apparently not all of the documents came out exactly the same. Here is what I tried:

```
def table_parser(page):
    file = open(page)
    table = []
    num = 0
    for line in file:
        if 'Grade' in line:
            num += 1
        if num > 0:
            num += 1
        if 3 <= num < 21:
            line = line.rstrip()
            if line != '':
                split_line = line.split(' ')
                split_line = [x for x in split_line if x != '']
                strip_line = split_line[:16]
                table.append(strip_line)
    WG = []
    WL = []
    WS = []
    for l in table:
        WG.append((l[1:6]))
        WL.append(l[6:11])
        WS.append(l[11:16])

    file.close()
    # Return 3 lists for the 3 charts I want
    return WG, WL, WS
```

This is what I used that got the about half of the 65k files I started with mostly right. I passed the returned lists into csv writers to store them till I can get them all cleaned up. I know there is probably a better way but I came up with this before I could wrap my head around BeautifulSoup. I don't necessarily want the code to do this, just pointers on where to start. I tried to find documentation on BeautifulSoup but I couldn't figure out where to start for what I need.

Comment: This is called web-scraping, and in Python the best free tool is BeautifulSoup. Try BS out and if you have a specific question, post your code and error here.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little vague so I'll try my best to help you.

### 1. Install Beautiful Soup 4

To get a block of text from a webpage,you will need to use the external library BeautifulSoup4 (BS4). Once downloaded and installed to your computer, first import BS4 using the following `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`and `import urllib.request`. Then simply setup BS4 using `soup = BeautifulSoup("", "html.parser")`.

### 2. Download Webpage

Downloading a webpage is simple, just use `site_download = urllib.request.urlopen(url)`. In your case, simply replace "url" with the url you provided here. Then we need to read what we've downloaded using `site_read = site_download.read().decode('utf-8')` followed by `soup = BeautifulSoup(site_read, "html.parser")`.

### 3. Get Block of Text

You can get text in many different ways, so I'll show you a few examples.

To get the first instance of  < P > tag (paragraph) text:

```
text = soup.find("p")
text = getText()
```

To get all instances of the < P > tag:

```
text = soup.findAll("p")
text = getText()
```

To get text from a specific class:

```
text = soup.find(attrs={"class": "class_name_here"})
text = getText()
```

### 4. Further Info

More information on how to get different types of tags and other things you can do with BS4 can be found [HERE](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Comment: I understand how to get the HTML, I have retrieved 65 thousand of them. I used my function that I wrote to parse them. About 28k of them retrieved the information I need, some need a little cleaning up but the remaining 30k+ didn't parse out right. I am returning 3 lists from my function each should be 15 lists of 5 elements. I am trying to find a way to parse out the block that I showed in OP. If you look at the source of the page the whole body of the text is basically in one <pre></pre>block. so really beautiful soup isn't going to get me any further, based off of your answer.